# How to loop GET_BULK in net-snmp?

Tags: c, sockets, snmp, net-snmp

I am using this code to loop the GET_BULK multiple times to get the logs of a Switch. I am using loop because there are a lot of values in the logs subtree. This code works perfectly fine except for the fact that it only prints the data for one GET_BULK request. The output of this code is same as that of when I use GETBULK in the MIB Browser. At first I thought it might be an issue with the output buffer of C, but now it seems like it has some problem with the GET_BULK buffer or either the loop logic.
I am new to net-snmp, and can't find where I am going wrong with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>

int main()
{
    oid target_oid[] = {1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 89, 82, 2, 9, 1, 6};
    size_t target_oid_len = OID_LENGTH(target_oid);

    init_snmp("snmpget");

    // SNMP
    netsnmp_session session, *ss;
    snmp_sess_init(&session);
    session.peername = strdup("172.16.100.32");
    session.version = SNMP_VERSION_2c;
    session.community = "public";
    session.community_len = strlen(session.community);

    // Sock
    SOCK_STARTUP;
    ss = snmp_open(&session);
    if (!ss)
    {
        snmp_perror("snmp_open");
        SOCK_CLEANUP;
        exit(1);
    }

    // SNMP
    netsnmp_pdu *response;
    netsnmp_pdu *pdu;
    int status;

    int start_index = 1;
    int num_requests = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_requests; i++)
    {
        pdu = snmp_pdu_create(SNMP_MSG_GETBULK);
        pdu->non_repeaters = 0;
        pdu->max_repetitions = 1000;
        
        snmp_pdu_add_variable(pdu, target_oid, target_oid_len, ASN_NULL, NULL, 0);

        pdu->variables->name[target_oid_len - 1] = start_index + i;
        pdu->variables->name_length = target_oid_len + 1;

        status = snmp_synch_response(ss, pdu, &response);

        if (status == STAT_SUCCESS && response->variables)
        {
            for (netsnmp_variable_list *vars = response->variables; vars; vars = vars->next_variable)
            {
                if (vars->name[11] == 6 && vars->name[9] == 9)
                {
                    printf("%.*s\n", (int)vars->val_len, vars->val.string);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", snmp_api_errstring(snmp_errno));
            snmp_sess_perror("snmpget", ss);
        }

        // Clean up
        snmp_free_pdu(response);
    }

    snmp_close(ss);
    SOCK_CLEANUP;

    return 0;
}
```